# Should I retain or assign the viewcontroller in this case?

Tags: iphone

Interface

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) PracticalSignsMainViewController *practicalVC;
```

Implementation

```
if (self.practicalVC == nil) {
    PracticalSignsMainViewController *vc = [[PracticalSignsMainViewController alloc] init];
    self.practicalVC = vc;
    [vc release];
}
```

I only want to make one viewcontroller object in this case and change the data that it acts upon. However is it correct to retain or assign this viewcontroller (and why so)? It is used in a navigation-hierachy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code is right, but it can be more simple.

If you did the following synthesize,

```
@synthesize practicalVC; // synthesize release the existing reference if has
```

the following code is same as your code.

```
self.practicalVC = [[[PracticalSignsMainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

As you mentioned, if your app does not need many access to the view controller, you need not to have view controller's instance separately.

============== Modified ====================
And I modified my answer after seeing answers of @6NSString @Abizern.
Regarding autorelease and coding style.

**1. autorelease,**
@6NSString said that "it uses autorelease which many avoid unless returning an newly alloced object."
*But even if you use "autorelease" in return statement, the retain count of the returned object is not immediately decreased. It will be decreased at an appropriate time.*

So If we want to decrease the retaincount explicitly and immediately, we should use paired "release".

```
-(NSObject*)testAuto {  
    return  [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
}
...
self.anObj = [self testAuto]; 
// the retainCount of anObj is 2
```

..

```
-(void)testAuto {
    self.anObj = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
}
...
[self testAuto];
// the retainCount of anObj is also 2
```

..

```
-(void)testAuto {   
    self.anObj = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.anObj release]; // Yes, yes, you may say this code does not look good. :)
}
...
[self testAuto]
// the retainCount of anObj is 1
```

...

As you see, (I naturally tested above code again) "autorelease"s both in return statement and in alloc statement are almost same. And if you want to manage retain count harder, we should use "release".
*I think "autorelease" in alloc statement is better than one in return statement because "autorelease" in return can be omitted. :)*

**2. Coding style,**
As the end of "1. autorelease", I think, autorelease in alloc statement would be more safe to avoid missing release.

Comment: Your code is the same as what the OP has, but it uses autorelease which many avoid unless returning an newly alloced object.

Comment: Apart from the misplaced advice about autorelease; writing all the code in one line doesn't make the code more efficient and may make it harder to read. Write code for human readability and let the compiler optimise the code for efficiency.

Comment: @Abizern What's misplaced about it? Maybe it's not complete (certainly there are many other reasons to use autorelease), but I believe I'm fundamentally correct. Many programmers use autorelease as a copout, or as a result of incorrectly understanding Obj-C memory management.

Comment: @6NSString - the comment was for alones, not for you. autorelease has it's uses, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @6NSString @Abizern Ok you are right (or partially right). And thanks for your comments. Please see my modified answer after soon.

Comment: @alones: Not sure what point you're trying to get at here, but your third example not only makes no sense, it's a crasher bug -- it will cause an object in an instance variable to be deallocated when the autorelease pool is deallocated. According to Apple's Memory Management Guide, you shouldn't be trying to keep track of retain counts at all, but rather thinking in terms of ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Retain. Typically you want object properties to be `retain`ed, and primitive properties to be `assign`ed. The answer here is really good: [Use of properties for primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424962/use-of-properties-in-objective-c-2-0-for-primitive-types)

Comment: I would also add that class clusters with mutable/immutable counterparts (such as NSString, NSArray, etc) be `copy`ed.

Comment: agreed. I neglected to mention copy.

Comment: Hang on... His setter is retaining it, why does he need to re retain it again?

Comment: that was the question, should his setter retain or assign. his code is correct as is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to cache a view controller that's used in a navigation, you would need to retain it. The reason is that while the navigation controller retains it temporarily, once the user hits the back button the navigation controller will send the view controller a `release` message. If you haven't retained the view controller anywhere else at that point it will be deallocated.

If you're creating a new instance each time, that would be fine, but obviously that would destroy a cached instance if the property uses `assign` semantics.